# error value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, api, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I am getting error value:`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).`

I have a app Flask. I want to use `Rest api`. I have a `app.py` file and `api.py` file.I am writing a `get` method in `api.py`file. This method have a input parameter(`P_ID`) and output of this method is `JSON` type. This method run correctly. Now, I want to use `requests.get` in `app.py` but I encountered this error.

my code in `app.py` file is:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:P_ID>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def update(P_ID):
    if request.method=='GET':
        info = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/edit/<int:P_ID>')
        info = info.json()
    return info
```

my `api.py` file is:

```
class ProductEdit(Resource):
    def get(self,P_ID):
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Tbl_product WHERE P_ID=?",(P_ID))
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        results = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        rest = jsonify(results)
        return rest

api.add_resource(ProductEdit , '/edit/<int:P_ID>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
info = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/edit/<int:P_ID>')
```

Should be (for Python3.6 or greater)

```
info = requests.get(f'http://localhost:5000/edit/{P_ID}')
```

The `<int:P_ID>` syntax is for flask routing/parsing - it's not a normal python string formatting syntax

You should also check the response from the request, a simple way to do it is to check the status code

```
if info.status_code != 200:
    # return a helpful error message here
```

Comment: I checked the response from the request. My response not equal ```200```.

Answer (score 0):

Also, My problem solved by this code:

```
info = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/edit/' + str(P_ID))
```